# IBM Watson Project. How do I re-access my notebook in an active project after logging out

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio

I have just started IBM Watson Studio. I created a project within which I created a Jupyter notebook. I logged out of it and want to login again after 30 minutes. I do not find any provision to open an existing project even though I am able to create a new project

Comment: Is this about Watson Studio in Cloud, Local, or Desktop? In Cloud and Local, there is a list of projects you have access to. You should find your project there. Note that in Cloud, we have separate deployments in US, UK, EU and Japan. If you created a project in US, you won't see it in the UK deployment, for example. Check the hostname in the URL. The non-US regions have an extra domain level there, like `eu-gb` or `eu-de`.

Comment: I am using cloud. I am able to see my projects listed as active but there seems to be no provision to retrieve my notebook and continue with my existing project. Instead I only find a provision to create a new project every time I log in

Comment: Click on Hamburger menu on left and click Projects -> View All Projects

Answer (score 0):

In the list of projects, click on the name of your project. In the project, switch to the Assets tab, where you'll see list of your notebooks in that project.

To edit a notebook, click on the Pencil icon in the same line. If you click on the name of the notebook, it will open in view mode rather than edit mode. But you'll have another Pencil icon at the top, so you can switch to editing from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your watson studio. Click on the IBM cloud at the top left corner. Choose dashboard click on services. Select Watson Studio-62. In the new window click on get started. Then in recently updated projects you will be able to see your project. Click on that. Then a new window will get opened. There you can see Notebooks. Click on the name of your note book. Click on the pencil icon to edit the note book..